# CSS code to modify reading from english digits to danish digits

Tags: css, data-conversion, digits

In a software i have a CSS code that should create color formatting in a spreadsheet (the spreadsheet is included in a html report created from the software).
I have the needed CSS code which works for reports in english. But i face an issue hence the danish digits are like this (4,1) instead of (4.1), hence the language code in the software is danish, the code don't work as it can't read digits as (4,1). Is there a way i can change the code so it reads "danish" digits instead of english? (there is a danish and a english version of the report, and i need the danish version to work and i cant remove the danish language package from the software).

The code below is the one used, which is not working on dansih digits. If i just modify the digits in the code to (3,5) the formatting is not working. Is there a way to modify the code so the formatiing is based on danish digits?
I have very limited understanding of coding :-) Any help is really appriciated.

```
&quot;<style type="text/css">
div.SpreadsheetBlockRow.TableContainer table{
    font-size: 8pt;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.onload = function() {
    var tableCells = document.querySelectorAll('div.SpreadsheetBlockRow.TableContainer td'),
      tableCellsArray = Array.from(tableCells),
      number;
    tableCellsArray.forEach(function(cell) {
      number = Number(cell.textContent);
      if (number <= 2.99){
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#244061';
      }
      else if (number >= 3 && number <= 3.499){
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#366092';
      }
       else if (number >= 3.5 && number <= 3.99){
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#95b3d7';
      }
      else if (number >= 4 && number <= 4.499){
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#b8cce4';
      }
      else if (number >= 4.5 && number <= 5){
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#dbe5f1';
      }
    });
  };
</script>&quot;
```

I expect the color formatting to work in the danish version of the report, but there is just no formatting when i just change the digits in the code from (4.1) to (4,1)

Answer (score 1):

#### How to can solve with **CSS**?

**CSS is not suitable** for replacing characters in the text, as CSS deals with the appearance and style, not the content of the text. Character replacement is usually done with JavaScript.

#### Solution

With **JavaScript can** use:

```js
cell.textContent.replace('.', ',')
```

If I understand correctly, then `cell.textContent` is of type string. So, you can replace `.` to `,` in text.

If it's not already of string type, you can convert it to one: `toString()`

Or you can use `NumberFormat`:

```js
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('da-DK', { style: 'decimal' });
const formattedNumber = formatter.format(cell.textContent);
```

#### Example

```js
// if cell.textContent is string
tableCellsArray = tableCellsArray.map(function (cell) {

  // Replace . to ,
  cell.textContent = cell.textContent.replace('.', ',');

  return cell;
});


// if cell.textContent is number
const formatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('da-DK', { style: 'decimal' });
tableCellsArray = tableCellsArray.map(function (cell) {

  // It's worth saving the formatted value in a separate key
  // so that the original number format is preserved,
  // and the Danish format can be displayed on the screen.
  cell.danishTextContent = formatter.format(cell.textContent);

  return cell;
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. Greatly appriciated

Comment: @Jacob, Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.